# C++, position of the "const" keyword in function signature

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, constants

What is difference between these function signatures?

```
void func(const std::shared_ptr<TestStruct>& ts) {...}
```

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<TestStruct> const& ts) {...}
```

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<TestStruct> &const ts) {...}
```

Comment: well the last one wont compile.  The first two are exactly the same.

Comment: All of these variants successfully compilled. VS 2019, C++14

Comment: Unrelated, but taking a `std::shared_ptr` by reference seems a bit weird. If that function (or something within it) needs to become a new owner of the data, it would make more sense to accept it by value. Alternatively, if you don't care about the shared-ownership offered by `std::shared_ptr` and really just care about the underlying `TestStruct`, you may as well just take the `TestStruct` directly by reference.

Comment: @ВалентинНикин Turn up your warning options.  I get *warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored* for the last one.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok, so is the third variant meaningless?

Comment: Yes.  references by their very nature are already `const` because the can't be changed after they are initialized.  A constant reference is redundant and not legal grammar, unless it is formed in a template context

Comment: I see, thank you